# Google Apps Script: creation of PDF Documents out of Spreadsheet data and providing the PDF URL into the Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I am trying to create PDF Documents with Spreadsheet Data and I wanna paste the PDF URLs of the created PDF Documents back into the Spreadsheet.

My Code seems to be working mostly, it creates the Temp Google Docs and PDF Files but its not working to paste the PDF URL back into my Spreadsheet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

My Code looks like the following:

```
const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of Doc");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Folder");
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Folder");


function createbBulkPDFs() {


const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of File");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Folder");
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Folder");
const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("[Script] Invoice generator");
const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,20).getDisplayValues();


let errors =[];
data.forEach(row => {
 try{
 createPDF(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[7],row[8] + row[7],row[9],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[15],row[16],row[17],row[18],row[19],row[0] + " " + row[8] + row[7],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
 errors.push([pdfContentBlob.getUrl()]);
 } catch(err){
   errors.push(["Failed"]);
 }
});


currentSheet.getRange(2,22,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(errors);




}




function createPDF(Companyname,Street,ZipCity,Country,VATNo,PO,Customernumber,Invoicenumber,Invoicedate,Invoiceperiod,Monthlyprice,Months,Net,VAT,Total,Reversecharge,Paymentterm,pdfName,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {
 // let Companyname = "ABC Inc";
// let Street = "Address";
// let ZipCity = "123 City";
// let Country = "Country";
// let VATNo = "789";
// let PO = "100";//
// let Customernumber = "Customer";
// let Invoicenumber = "Invoice";
// let Invoicedate = "Invoicedate";
// let Invoiceperiod = "period";
// let Monthlyprice = "3.000";
// let Months = "12";
// let Net = "36.000";
// let VAT = "6.840";
// let Total = "42.840";
// let Reversecharge = "No reverse";
// let Paymentterm = "14";


//Template Doc: 1SviyOCJYVYoBcg88wSyyv_VL_zChDAbDy5pjQ6iXXnw
//temp files: 1YpQYzN9tbQni7cl3WWO6EiKBXvM04-Kx
//invoices: 1gOEbnnrVkdPSSNCh31fBgEnsZD7croNK




const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder).setName(pdfName);
const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
body.replaceText("{Companyname}",Companyname);
body.replaceText("{Street}",Street);
body.replaceText("{ZipCity}",ZipCity);
body.replaceText("{Country}",Country);
body.replaceText("{VATNo}",VATNo);
body.replaceText("{PO}",PO);
body.replaceText("{Customernumber}",Customernumber);
body.replaceText("{Invoicenumber}",Invoicenumber);
body.replaceText("{Invoicedate}",Invoicedate);
body.replaceText("{Invoiceperiod}",Invoiceperiod);
body.replaceText("{Monthlyprice}",Monthlyprice);
body.replaceText("{Months}",Months);
body.replaceText("{Net}",Net);
body.replaceText("{VAT}",VAT);
body.replaceText("{Total}",Total);
body.replaceText("{Reversecharge}",Reversecharge);
body.replaceText("{Paymentterm}",Paymentterm);
tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs('application/pdf');
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this updated code to paste the PDF URL back into your Spreadsheet:

```
function createbBulkPDFs() {

  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of Doc"); // template doc
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Folder"); // // template folder
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Folder"); // pdf folder
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("[Script] Invoice generator");
  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 20).getDisplayValues();

  let errors = [];
  data.forEach(row => {
    try {
      const pdfUrl = createPDF(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[7], row[8] + row[7], row[9], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[0] + " " + row[8] + row[7], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
      errors.push([pdfUrl]); // updated this code
    } catch (err) {
      errors.push(["Failed"]);
    }
  });
  currentSheet.getRange(2, 22, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(errors);
}


function createPDF(Companyname, Street, ZipCity, Country, VATNo, PO, Customernumber, Invoicenumber, Invoicedate, Invoiceperiod, Monthlyprice, Months, Net, VAT, Total, Reversecharge, Paymentterm, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder) {

  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder).setName(pdfName);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Companyname}", Companyname);
  body.replaceText("{Street}", Street);
  body.replaceText("{ZipCity}", ZipCity);
  body.replaceText("{Country}", Country);
  body.replaceText("{VATNo}", VATNo);
  body.replaceText("{PO}", PO);
  body.replaceText("{Customernumber}", Customernumber);
  body.replaceText("{Invoicenumber}", Invoicenumber);
  body.replaceText("{Invoicedate}", Invoicedate);
  body.replaceText("{Invoiceperiod}", Invoiceperiod);
  body.replaceText("{Monthlyprice}", Monthlyprice);
  body.replaceText("{Months}", Months);
  body.replaceText("{Net}", Net);
  body.replaceText("{VAT}", VAT);
  body.replaceText("{Total}", Total);
  body.replaceText("{Reversecharge}", Reversecharge);
  body.replaceText("{Paymentterm}", Paymentterm);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs('application/pdf');
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName) // updated this code
  return pdfFile.getUrl(); // added this code

}
```

Since there's no sample Spreadsheet provided, I've created a test Spreadsheet and here's the output:

[image]

I've modified/add the following to your code:

```
const pdfUrl = createPDF(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[7], row[8] + row[7], row[9], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[0] + " " + row[8] + row[7], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
          errors.push([pdfUrl]); // modified this code
```

---

```
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName) // updated this code
  return pdfFile.getUrl(); // added this code
```

**Reference:**

- [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl())

Comment: Thank you! It worked and helped a lot. Really appreciate your help.